# get_file_contents get json parameter

Tags: php

Please get "shortUrl" Parameter
Not Work

```
          $json_string = file_get_contents('http://ow.ly/api/1.1/url/shorten?apiKey=APICODE&longUrl=' . urlencode($url));
      $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

      $shorten=$json['shortUrl'];
```

Comment: What do you try to do??

Comment: Can you show the value of $json_string?

Comment: http://byvolkan.com/short/ - demo site select ow.ly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually look at the response from ow.ly you'll see that it's:

```
{"results":{"hash":"3hGIhh","longUrl":"http:\/\/www.stackoverflow.com","shortUrl":"http:\/\/ow.ly\/3hGIhh"}}
```

So you need to do the following:

```
$shortUrl = $json->results->shortUrl;
```

Or possibly

```
$shortUrl = $json['results']['shortUrl'];
```